# Prevent BroadcastBlock from sending buffered message on LinkTo

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Given a `BroadcastBlock` with a message in the buffer, is it possible to prevent that message from being sent to newly linked targets? For example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myBroadcastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<string>(msg => msg);
    var myActionBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));

    myBroadcastBlock.Post("Hello World!"); // No linked targets here.

    myBroadcastBlock.LinkTo(myActionBlock); // Link a target.

    // etc.
}
```

This code will print "Hello World". Basically, the `BroadcastBlock` will still send the buffered message to the `ActionBlock` on `.LinkTo`, despite the message having been posted prior to the link being established.

Is there a built-in way to prevent this behavior? I only want messages to be sent to current links, not future ones.

I am using [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow 4.11.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/4.11.1)

Comment: According to my understanding each `DataFlowBlock` maintains an queue, which size can be controlled by the `BoundedCapacity`. The only exception that I'm aware of is the `WriteOnceBlock`. You can't control this behaviour even through a `DataflowLinkOptions` instance during linking.

Comment: The `LinkTo()` method appears to call `OfferCurrentMessageToNewTarget(target)` internally. So I don't think you can prevent this behavior. You would need to rebuild your pipeline. Use the Complete method on the existing BroadcastBlock (and wait for completion) then re-instantiate it as new, and then link all required blocks.

Comment: @SeanOB Yeah this is what I was afraid of :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not possible using the built-in [`BroadcastBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.broadcastblock-1) class. Its behavior is not configurable. If you desperately need this behavior, you could try the implementation below. It uses an internal `BroadcastBlock<(T, long)>` with an index that is incremented with each new message, so that during linking the currently active message can be filtered out.

There is quite a lot of indirection inside the `BroadcastBlockNewOnly` class, because of the need to translate from `T` to `(T, long)` and back to `T`. This makes the class hard to maintain, and also not very efficient. On every received message a new object is allocated, creating more work for the garbage collector, so use this class with caution.

```
public class BroadcastBlockNewOnly<T> : ITargetBlock<T>, ISourceBlock<T>
{
    private readonly IPropagatorBlock<(T, long), (T, long)> _broadcastBlock;
    private long _index;

    public BroadcastBlockNewOnly(Func<T, T> cloningFunction,
        DataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions = null)
    {
        if (cloningFunction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cloningFunction));
        _broadcastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<(T, long)>(entry =>
        {
            var (value, index) = entry;
            return (cloningFunction(value), index);
        }, dataflowBlockOptions ?? new DataflowBlockOptions());
    }

    public Task Completion => _broadcastBlock.Completion;
    public void Complete() => _broadcastBlock.Complete();
    void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception ex) => _broadcastBlock.Fault(ex);

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<T> target, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
    {
        if (target == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));
        var currentIndex = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _index, 0, 0);
        var linkedTargetProxy = new LinkedTargetProxy(target, this, currentIndex);
        return _broadcastBlock.LinkTo(linkedTargetProxy, linkOptions);
    }

    private long GetNewIndex() => Interlocked.Increment(ref _index);

    DataflowMessageStatus ITargetBlock<T>.OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader header,
        T value, ISourceBlock<T> source, bool consumeToAccept)
    {
        var sourceProxy = source != null ?
            new SourceProxy(source, this, GetNewIndex) : null;
        return _broadcastBlock.OfferMessage(header, (value, GetNewIndex()),
            sourceProxy, consumeToAccept);
    }

    T ISourceBlock<T>.ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader header,
        ITargetBlock<T> target, out bool messageConsumed)
    {
        var targetProxy = target != null ? new TargetProxy(target, this) : null;
        var (value, index) = _broadcastBlock.ConsumeMessage(header, targetProxy,
            out messageConsumed);
        return value;
    }

    bool ISourceBlock<T>.ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader header,
        ITargetBlock<T> target)
    {
        var targetProxy = target != null ? new TargetProxy(target, this) : null;
        return _broadcastBlock.ReserveMessage(header, targetProxy);
    }

    void ISourceBlock<T>.ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader header,
        ITargetBlock<T> target)
    {
        var targetProxy = target != null ? new TargetProxy(target, this) : null;
        _broadcastBlock.ReleaseReservation(header, targetProxy);
    }

    private class LinkedTargetProxy : ITargetBlock<(T, long)>
    {
        private readonly ITargetBlock<T> _realTarget;
        private readonly ISourceBlock<T> _realSource;
        private readonly long _indexLimit;

        public LinkedTargetProxy(ITargetBlock<T> realTarget, ISourceBlock<T> realSource,
            long indexLimit)
        {
            _realTarget = realTarget;
            _realSource = realSource;
            _indexLimit = indexLimit;
        }

        DataflowMessageStatus ITargetBlock<(T, long)>.OfferMessage(
            DataflowMessageHeader header, (T, long) messageValue,
            ISourceBlock<(T, long)> source, bool consumeToAccept)
        {
            var (value, index) = messageValue;
            if (index <= _indexLimit) return DataflowMessageStatus.Declined;
            return _realTarget.OfferMessage(header, value, _realSource, consumeToAccept);
        }

        Task IDataflowBlock.Completion => throw new NotSupportedException();
        void IDataflowBlock.Complete() => _realTarget.Complete();
        void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception ex) => _realTarget.Fault(ex);
    }

    private class SourceProxy : ISourceBlock<(T, long)>
    {
        private readonly ISourceBlock<T> _realSource;
        private readonly ITargetBlock<T> _realTarget;
        private readonly Func<long> _getNewIndex;

        public SourceProxy(ISourceBlock<T> realSource, ITargetBlock<T> realTarget,
            Func<long> getNewIndex)
        {
            _realSource = realSource;
            _realTarget = realTarget;
            _getNewIndex = getNewIndex;
        }

        (T, long) ISourceBlock<(T, long)>.ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader header,
            ITargetBlock<(T, long)> target, out bool messageConsumed)
        {
            var value = _realSource.ConsumeMessage(header, _realTarget,
                out messageConsumed);
            var newIndex = _getNewIndex();
            return (value, newIndex);
        }

        bool ISourceBlock<(T, long)>.ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader header,
            ITargetBlock<(T, long)> target)
        {
            return _realSource.ReserveMessage(header, _realTarget);
        }

        void ISourceBlock<(T, long)>.ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader header,
            ITargetBlock<(T, long)> target)
        {
            _realSource.ReleaseReservation(header, _realTarget);
        }

        Task IDataflowBlock.Completion => throw new NotSupportedException();
        void IDataflowBlock.Complete() => throw new NotSupportedException();
        void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception ex) => throw new NotSupportedException();
        IDisposable ISourceBlock<(T, long)>.LinkTo(ITargetBlock<(T, long)> target,
            DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    private class TargetProxy : ITargetBlock<(T, long)>
    {
        private readonly ITargetBlock<T> _realTarget;
        private readonly ISourceBlock<T> _realSource;

        public TargetProxy(ITargetBlock<T> realTarget, ISourceBlock<T> realSource)
        {
            _realTarget = realTarget;
            _realSource = realSource;
        }

        DataflowMessageStatus ITargetBlock<(T, long)>.OfferMessage(
            DataflowMessageHeader header, (T, long) messageValue,
            ISourceBlock<(T, long)> source, bool consumeToAccept)
        {
            var (value, index) = messageValue;
            return _realTarget.OfferMessage(header, value, _realSource, consumeToAccept);
        }

        Task IDataflowBlock.Completion => throw new NotSupportedException();
        void IDataflowBlock.Complete() => throw new NotSupportedException();
        void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception ex) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a smart solution and has the behavior I am looking for—thanks! Given the warranted cautionary tale about the allocation of new objects and general class maintenance, I'm wondering if there is a more streamlined workaround out there? I'm optimistic, but seems unlikely, given all the hoops you had to go through to create a new type of object with the desired behavior.

Comment: @JacobShanley this is the simplest solution I could think of. You could probably make it less allocatey by maintaining internally a cache of `SourceProxy` and `TargetProxy` instances, but this would complicate the class even further. I think that if you don't pass through the pipeline thousands of messages per second, and don't have a specific reason to keep the garbage collector idle (like programming a game), the current implementation should be good enough.

Comment: @JacobShanley Sorry to say, but this seems to me a bit overkill. It looks like you want to use the wrong tool for this problem. An Observable might be a better fit for this. You can convert any DataFlowObject to Observable by calling the `AsObservable` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.asobservable?view=netcore-3.1))

Comment: @PeterCsala Yeah, Observable is a good call. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterCsala the Rx equivalent of the `BroadcastBlock` is the [`BehaviorSubject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211949(v=vs.103)), which has a similar behavior when subscribed (it propagates the last value it received). The behavior requested by the OP is probably matched by a simple [`Subject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229173(v=vs.103)).