# TPL Dataflow BroadcastBlock: Automatically clear the block after it has broadcasted the element to linked targets?

Tags: tpl-dataflow

Given a scenario where I have a BroadcastBlock and 5 linked targets. When I send an element to BroadcastBlock, each of the linked targets will get the element automatically. This works great.

**The problem**: If I have this configuration (1 BroadcastBlock & 5 linked targets) and then decide to add a 6th linked target, runtime, the newly linked target instantly receives the last element sent to the BroadcastBlock. This must mean that after successfully broadcasting the newly received element to the listeners, this element stays in the BroadcastBlock until it has been replaced with a new element? And if I add a new listener, it will get the element when the linking happens.

**What I expected**: If an element is sent to BroadcastBlock and the block successfully broadcasts the element to its 5 listeners, the element is automatically removed from the BroadcastBlock. So when I add a new listener, it doesn't receive anything until I send a new element to BroadcastBlock.

**Question:** Is it possible to clear the BroadcastBlock after it has successfully broadcasted the newly added element to its current listeners?

Comment: Related: [Prevent BroadcastBlock from sending buffered message on LinkTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63160739/prevent-broadcastblock-from-sending-buffered-message-on-linkto)